# erlang : ordering of trace messages originating from a single process

Tags: erlang, trace

That is the simple question, i can not find a clear answer to:

Can one assume that the order of trace messages belonging to a *single* process are sent in the order in which corresponding events occur ?

(The icing on the cake would of course be the source where is is specified :) )

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Messages from a process A to a process B are guaranteed to always be ordered. It would be right to assume the trace events will also be ordered.

This guarantee doesn't hold when many processes message another one: if A and C both message B and A fires before C, there is no guarantee that A's message will be there first. Similarly, if A messages both B and C, there is no guarantee that C won't have its messages before B.

This could cause confusion if there is IO being done while tracing -- IO goes through a specific process (the group leader) that acts as a server, so outputting trace vs. stuff that is happening right now might give funny results.

Comment: (...continuing), still i'm somewhat at unease about this - true there are some strong guarantees on message semantics. http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:2J0_HZby-4IJ:citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.114.5670%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dps+erlang+order+of+trace+messages&cd=14&hl=de&ct=clnk&gl=de&client=firefox-a  even claims that some trace events are completely lost but does not investigate further :/ so how do i ask what you base "It would be right to assume the trace events will also be ordered." on without sounding like a complete ass ?